# Routing in Kohana without changing URL

Tags: php, kohana-3

How can I re-rout execution to another controller/action in Kohana PHP framework, w/o redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using default routing you can do this:

```
Request::factory('welcome/index2')->execute();
```

General case:

```
$this->request
    ->controller('welcome')
    ->action('index2')
    ->execute();
```

Or look at [Request->execute()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Request#execute)